# Search Refinement web part refines empty results when clicking authors from "Show More"

Tags: 2013, search, refiner

I am using search refinement web part to refine search results web part results. When clicking the author from search refinement web part can refines results but after clicking show more authors and clicking same refine not working. Anyone help me to get out of this..

[image]

After clicking 'test' it refines results

[image]

[image]

But clicking same 'test' in drop down not working

[image]

Anyone help me to get out of this...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check whether search page is set to searchable? You can check this under search settings→search and offline availability.

And also please re-index the site.

Is this SPOnline or else SP2013 Onpremise?

Comment: SP2013 Onpremise

Comment: I have tried reindex but it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried full crawl for that particular site

Comment: Yes....Still not works